# Eliminar algunas funciones de WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy modificando un tema para WordPress, he estado buscando una solución para eliminar algunas funciones dentro de Woocommerce pero no logro encontrar una solución:

1. ¿Cómo puedo eliminar la imagen del producto de WooCommerce en la galería? Porque esta imagen se agrega automáticamente y no se puede borrar.

IMÁGENES: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKCIc.jpg

2. ¿Cómo puedo desactivar la página del carrito, es posible? Solo me interesa la página de Checkout. He estado mirando algunos códigos pero no permiten seleccionar más de 2 productos.

Saludos a todos los que comenten, espero que estas cuestiones puedan ayudar a más personas en el futuro.

Comment: bienvenido a SO en Español, deberías traducir tu pregunta al idioma del sitio, de otra forma lo más probables es que la acaben eliminando,

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas eliminar el siguiente parámetro en functions.php:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );
```

a través del css, atacando a la clase/id que corresponda.Ejemplo:

```
 .woocommerce_show_product_images {display:none}
```

Comment: Perdona no sabía que estaba en la parte del foro en español, mis disculpas. Gracias por el código Jorge, pero ahora se ha eliminado todo el bloque de imágenes y solo me interesa que se elimine la primera, es decir, la imagen del producto dentro de la galería. https://imgur.com/a/CEFfqcL

Comment: Ok, ahora entendí lo que necesitas, en este caso concreto si se trata de solo eliminar esa imagen, yo atacaría la clase o id que lo monta y a través del css lo eliminaria del DOM. Ejemplo (nombre de la clase/id sea en concreto):

.woocommerce_show_product_images {display:none}

Comment: Hola JorgeGuz, probaré a ver que tal. Una pregunta, cómo añado el id al código css?

Comment: pues en la hoja de estilos que corresponda y con el id que sea en concreto el que necesitas añades una línea con: #ID-QUE-SEA{display:none}

Comment: Por ejemplo, el id de ese producto es 582, ¿cómo quedaría? Gracias de antemano Jorge.

Comment: El id del contenedor o la clase que actúa sobre él, algo que te sirva para identificar donde carga y darle el estilo

Comment: Lo siento sigo sin entender, no soy informático y ese lenguaje me sobrepasa :) Puedes poner un ejemplo de ese código css con los id´s 582 y 144??

Comment: No te preocupes, no pasa nada, es normal entonces que no sepas a que me refiero, para poder ayudarte entonces necesito ver tu web y que exactamente me indiques la página en que tienes este problema.